# Angular 2 - Code is not executing in token callback (stripe)

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm using Angular2 and a custom form to create my stripe token. The code below executes `console.log(token.id)` correctly, however the `this.http.post...` isn't called. Even if I try to call another function instead eg `this.sayHello()`, it is still not called.

```
export class SubscriptionComponent{

  constructor(public http: Http){}

    openCheckout() {

    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_mykey',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function(token, args){
        console.log(token.id);

        this.http.post("/stripe/customer", token.id).subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          error => console.log(error)
        );
      }      
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo',
      description: '',
      amount: 990,
      currency: 'GBP',
      email: 'test@hotmail.co.uk'
    });
  }
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if HTTP request is sent via network tracker? 
Put 
console.log(this); 
after logging token.id to see what 'this' is

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who has this problem. I solved this by changing the token callback to this

```
token: token => {
        console.log(token.id);
        this.checkoutService.postToken(token);
      }
```

injecting a `checkoutService` service to handle the `http.post`. Not sure why this way works and the other didn't but there we go.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I have strange situation. I could call now service, but nothing happened on back-end side (of course I checked back-end side calling other function and all works fine).